# How to grab an attachment url from a specific channel?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, attachment, channel

I've got the following code and right now it's grabbing all attachments from any channel and sending it in the channel "luv" as an embed. I want it to only grab attachments from the "luv" channel and post the embed in "luv" also. Any help?

```
  client.on("message", async (message) => {
    const channel = message.guild.channels.find(channel => channel.name === "luv");
    if (!channel) return;
    message.attachments.forEach(attachment => { // do something with the attachment // changes all attachements into embed #luv
      if (message.deletable) {
        message.delete(1000)
        const url = attachment.url;
        const aesEmbed = new RichEmbed()
        .setImage(attachment.url)

        client.channels.get("678987398838747166").send(aesEmbed);
        console.log(attachment.url);
        }
      })
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check message channel ID or name for that.

```js
client.on("message", async (message) => {
    if (message.channel.id !== 'PLACE CHANNEL ID HERE') return //Stop function if channel ID !== 'luv' channeld.id 
    const channel = message.guild.channels.find(channel => channel.name === "luv");
    if (!channel) return;
    message.attachments.forEach(attachment => { // do something with the attachment // changes all attachements into embed #luv
        if (message.deletable) {
            message.delete(1000)
            const url = attachment.url;
            const aesEmbed = new RichEmbed()
                .setImage(attachment.url)
            client.channels.get("678987398838747166")
                .send(aesEmbed);
            console.log(attachment.url);
        }
    })
});
```

And realy better dont use `find by name` method to get channel.

Replace

```
const channel = message.guild.channels.find(channel => channel.name === "luv");
```

To

```js
const channel = message.guild.channels.get('CHANNEL ID')
```